# Any limits to Single Entry Tourist Visas per year? (Thailand)

Tags: visas, thailand

Have you encountered anyone having being rejected with this "kind of history":

1 Dec 2017 - Entered the Kingdom with a SE Tourist Visa (issued in Home Country - Sweden)

30 Jan 2018 - Extension 30 day at local IM

28 Feb 2018 - Went back to Home Country

~ 90 Days

1 Aug 2018 - Entered the Kingdom with a SE Tourist Visa (issued in Home Country - Sweden)

30 Sep 2018 - Extension 30 day

28 October - Left to Vietnam

~90 days (of which 150 in calendar year 2018)

30 October - Entered the Kingdom with a SE Tourist Visa (issued in Vietnam)

30 December - Extension 30 day

January 28 - Left to Vietnam

~90 days (of which 210 in calendar year 2018)

January 30 - Entered the Kingdom with a SE Tourist Visa (issued in Vietnam)

Would you say I have decent chances of entering Thailand on my third SETV "in a row"?

Can produce 20k, condo contract, flight ticket exiting Thailand etc.

- This "180 day rule" is it on a rolling 12 month period, or calendar year period? (Is it reset 2018/2019).
- This "180 day rule" apparently (if existing) wasn't enforced on my when entering Thailand on 30th of october again)

Comment: Upvoted for good organization.  Can you edit your OP to comment on how you enter/leave and which location?  e.g. air Chiang Mai, train Padang Besar, bus/walk Mukdahan, etc .   Also, can you explain your understanding of the `180 day` rule?

Comment: If you intend to stay long-term (over 180 days a year each year), have you considered a METV or an Elite visa?  Or do you qualify for any non-immigrant visa?

Answer (score 2):

**You should NOT have a problem entering.**  Should you somehow be flagged for suspicion of illegally working, you have the 20k THB + flight ticket out + rental contract (show only what they ask). There is nothing official that would prevent you from coming and being allowed to enter.  Unofficially, some immigration offices seem to be tracking extensions and *maybe* counting them as entries.  But again, your case should have no issues.  In the event that a particular airport is being difficult, consider a land entry or an alternate airport.

The problem with this question is that, while the OP does a great job of describing his travel history, different borders can have slightly different policies on what is acceptable.  For example, some Malay borders (like Sadao/Dannok) require an overnight stay (no same-day "out-in" bouncing).  The majority of the people should have no issues as there are many people who travel yearly to Thailand and do their winter months, 1/2 year thing, etc entirely on METV or SETV + [SETV/VE/Extension].

---

If you really want to stay in Thailand full time (greater than 8 months/270 days per year), consider METV, Elite Visa, or non-imm visa.  Your first year bouncing around isn't such a big deal.  Eventually it would get old, especially if you live very far from the more convenient land/air borders.

edit:  See a somewhat related post on [Visa Exempt entry limitation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88823/thailand-visa-exemption-any-rule-limiting-number-of-entries-per-year/88871#88871).