# How many consecutive tourist visas can I get from the Thai embassy in Vientiane now?

Tags: visas, thailand, laos

How many consecutive tourist visas can I get from the Thai embassy in Vientiane now?

I have a Swedish passport. I have two consecutive single entry visas to Thailand and I am in Chiang Mai at the moment. Prior to those visas I have also entered Thailand three times (2 in 2018, 1 in 2019) with the visa exemption 30 days given at the border.

How many consecutive tourist visas can I get in Vientiane at the moment without going to another country (not Laos) such as Vietnam or Japan in between?

And what is best practice at the moment?

Comment: What's your goal? To return as a tourist? Or are you 'working' in Chiang Mai?

Comment: Terasugiveraguela

Comment: not familiar with that word? Neither is google?

Answer (score 1):

> #### According to the most recent reports on `TV forum` and `TV Advice facebook group`, it is now *only 1 SETV per calendar year* at Vientiane Thai embassy.
>
> > **[Report #1](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1108651-denied-tourist-visa-at-vientiane-new-rule-1x-per-year/)   |   [Report #2](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1113150-vientiane-tourist-visa-update-many-people-denied/)   |   [Report #3](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1094774-my-experience-with-vientiane/)  |   [Report #4](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1395920320731833/permalink/2443674382623083/)   |   [Report #5](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1395920320731833/permalink/2490382344618953/)   |   [Report #6](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1395920320731833/permalink/2285111241812732/)**

The trend to close off easy ways for perpetual tourists to just hang out indefinitely via VE and SETV entries has been ongoing for the past 5 years.  I suggest looking to one of my previous answers that explains this trend in much greater detail:  [Thailand visa exemption: any rule limiting number of entries per year?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88823/thailand-visa-exemption-any-rule-limiting-number-of-entries-per-year/88871#88871)

**TL:DR??** They are pushing long-stay visitors towards non-immigrant or Elite visa categories.  **ME**TV is also worth considering, but are limited to obtaining only from a Thai consulate in your home country or country of residence.

---

**Tip:**  When starting your trip, obtaining at least 1 SETV (or METV) from Sweden/EU Thai consulate might be a good way to maximize your stay time.  Save the VEs for land border runs.

Comment: I have personally already received two SETV from the embassy this year. Those guys at thaivisa.com are not always a reliable source of information, with some notable exceptions. I do however appreciate your feedback specifically and will take it into consideration for my future plans. I'm not entirely sure that a 1 or even 2 SETV per calendar year maximum rule is always enforced, both because I have received two myself already without any red stamp and because you also still get mixed reports with some being successful with their applications. Is there any way to PM you on this platform?

Comment: I would need to see more details (history of entries last 2-3 years) and what was the atmosphere when you went last 2 times, I'm still correct about the larger visa trend.  TVF can be rough, but the visa section is mostly on topic. The semi-private FB group has much less judgement/bitching and is more direct advice.   Why no SE PM's? See [answers to this q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/325059) for why PM's are discouraged on SE.  (spend 2 hours combing through several links)