Can you enter a visa-free country multiple times?
I am from the UK. I am flying to Thailand. I do not need a visa to enter Thailand, and have visa-free entry for thirty days. I'm flying to Nepal three days after I enter Thailand, and then back to Thailand three weeks later. Will it be okay to enter Thailand twice like that and does my thirty day counter reset with each entry?

When do you plan on returning to the UK? If your exit/re-entry is part of say a planned tour, after which you’ll go home, you’re more than likely OK. If it’s a visa run or you don’t have firm plans to go home, the answer might be different.

Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153814/can-i-re-enter-thailand-the-day-my-permit-expires-and-get-a-new-one

not your actual question, but of potential note: under most circumstances, UK citizens visiting Thailand are given sixty days visa-free entry, not thirty.
